# Booking Uber ride for another person

Tags: uber-api

When i book ride on behalf of another person (person don't have Uber account) with my Uber account through Uber API.Is it possible to make the driver see the other person phone number instead of the phone number associated with my Uber account?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, phone calls from the rider to the driver are restricted to devices that match the phone number on the rider account.
[source of info](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/faq)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. There is no endpoint for that.